# What is Judaism's take on dying a virgin?

Tags: marriage, sexuality, family-members, reincarnation

I take it from the Torah that G'd commanded mankind to procreate and that pre-marital sex is forbidden and all that, But what happens with people who either choose to remain unmarried or otherwise virgin for their whole lives or the opportunity just never presented to them to marry or have children when they die? What do we learn from the Kabbalah of these people after they reincarnate?? what would their next life be like?

Comment: There are people who never married in the Talmud and it is regarded as a bad thing. Some say that instead of killing her, Yiftach had his daughter locked away so she did not marry for her entire life. [Shoftim 11:40](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15819/showrashi/true#v40) shows that the daughters of Israel mourned her situation.

Comment: @sabbahillel Even according to the opinions that Yiftach's daughter was killed, the verses are clear that they mourned her being a virgin at death.

Comment: @sabbahillel Even according to the opinions that Yiftach's daughter was killed, the verses are clear that they mourned her being a virgin at death.

Comment: Btw it's not just premarital sex but also postmarital sex. Seemingly extramarital sex is the better way to describe it.

Answer (score -1):

I can't speak for Kabbalah. But otherwise, I don't think there's anything specific about virginity per se.

Talmud Chagiga 14b says Ben Azai got too close to knowing God for a mortal, and therefore died. The verse remarks about him: *when the pious die, it's costly to God.* Rashi comments -- that he died as a young man.

So perhaps "oh what a shame", but that's about it.

Rabbi Moshe Feinstein was asked about not naming after a relative who suffered from particular poor fate; he wrote that someone who had children and then died of natural causes in their 50s is not, in the overall scheme of things, considered to be "an ill-fated relative." Of course does that mean that someone who lived to 110 and never married or had kids was "ill-fated?" I doubt it, but somehow having kids seems to weigh in to some degree.

Comment: The Gemara in sotah, in one answer, says Ben Azai was a divorcé not a virgin

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks! The first of three answers on 4b, right? And that would indicate he was explicitly a non-virgin. IIRC it's in Kesubos that says R' Akiva offered a massive dowry when Ben Azzai married his daughter, Tosfos goes with the "died a virgin" approach and suggests he got betrothed but then called it off from there. But *in hachi nami*, thank you.